# Origin of the Kaya Trayam system

Tags: vedanta, ayurveda

Can someone direct me to the origin of the Kaya Trayam doctrine? I find direct reference to it in Shankaracharya's Tattvabodha. But that does not seem to be the source. If you have any scholarly study on the development of the term overtime I would also be appreciative. But I would suffice if yo have an original source older than the Tattvabodha. I also udnerstood there is some reference in Ayurvedic sources.